# How to do UITextView scroll detect and change images

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

It looks like this :
[image]

[image]

(I can't show image please I don't have 10 prestiges)

```
let departmentMessage = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 1500 /      2, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 50, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 50)/4 ))
    showBlshText()
    departmentMessage.isScrollEnabled = true
    departmentMessage.isPagingEnabled = true
    departmentMessage.isEditable = false
    departmentMessage.isSelectable = true
    departmentMessage.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link 
    departmentMessage.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

    departmentMessage.textAlignment = .left
    departmentMessage.contentMode = .topLeft

    departmentMessage.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 20)
    departmentMessage.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 20)
    self.view.addSubview(departmentMessage)
    departmentMessage.removeFromSuperview()
```

I expect the output of the word to change, but the actual output isn't work.

Comment: the all images over here and I want it change images when I finish scroll to the right text to detection line. Don't care about colors or texts, btw "test1" and "test2" are ''the right text to detect" then change the background(image1 and image2). I only want this effect, don't need any others.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Why do you add departmentMessage and then immediately remove it?

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  So everything that a scrollView does a textView can do also.  In you case, it seems that you want to do some action when the textView is scrolled.  You should look the [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) documentation which describes how you can monitor a scrollView to see when it is scrolled.  There are a few tips to know:

- the delegate is not called when you set the content offset programatically.
- `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` is not called when `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` is called with NO for the `willDecelerate` value.

So just set your viewController as the delegate, implement the appropriate methods, and change your UI accordingly.

Also, you might have better luck using a UICollectionView or a UITableView.  Even if every row is just a label, it is far easier to track what indexPath is at the top of the collectionView then what text is at the top of textView. But without knowing exactly what you are doing it is hard to say.